# How to create a download button in html5

Tags: html

i have a html file a html file and a css file for my web page i need a download button on my site that downloads a specific file from some server i have created that download button usins the code :-

```
  <div class="formbutton">
    <form action ="C:\somePath\abc.xls" method="get">

            <button type="submit">Download Excel</button>

     </form>  
   </div>
```

but this is not working on clicking the download button its telling :

```
   Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/somePath/abc.xls?
```

i don't understand why because when i try the same code using some natepad file then opening it with browser it works .

please help me out with this issue

Answer (score 2):

Your path to the excel sheet is absolute. It should be relative.

You have to place your abc.xls file in the same directory as your HTML document. Then you give `<form action ="abc.xls" method="get">`

Answer (score 1):

Your path is absolute, whereas it needs to be relative.

Absolute path: means that it is the full **absolute** path from the root directory.

Relative path: means that it is a path **relative** from where the **HTML document** is.

if you move your excel document into the same folder as your html document, this will work:

```
<form action ="abc.xls" method="get">
```

To get to the folder above, you can add a double period (..) like so:

```
<form action ="..\abc.xls" method="get">
```

To get to a folder inside the HTML document folder:

```
<form action ="MyExcelFiles\abc.xls" method="get">
```

Answer (score 0):

On your page, the path to the file must be relative - not absolute like you are doing.

For instance, have the HTML page **and** in the same directory and address the download as abc.xls as opposed to C://home/user/documents/programming/html/site/abc.xls. You can do this as they will be in the same directory.

The line of code for this would be:

```
<form action ="abc.xls" method="get">
```

Relative means relative to the HTML document. Absolute is the path from the hard drive.

Good luck.

Comment: can you give some example for it  ..Thanks

Comment: For instance, have the html download page <b> and </b> the excel file in the same directory.